# get sum from complex array of hashes with dynamic keys (in Rails way)

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, collections

I have a complex collection of data in the form of array of hashes. I searched around and I found that `array.map{}` and `array.collect` can be used with `.reduce()` or `.inject()` methods to get sum of collection. But I am only able to do so with some very simple collection I am not able to get some for data in my situation. Here is some block of sample data.

```
    => [{"teacher_name"=>"Imran Ahmad", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>24}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>20}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>20}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"t@kpi.com", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>12}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>5}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>5}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"t2@kpi.com", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"tt@kpi.com", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"asd@kpi.con", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"Tofiq Ahmad", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]}]
```

I want this to be summed up in in following form;

```
"categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>224}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>220}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>320}]
```

Here in each hash is for unique category name. Let say hash for category `Presentation` represents the sum of all `weights` of this category in each hash and so on.
Any help to sort this out using short("Rails way") using these methods would be really appreciated.

Note: Category names are not assumed to be same each time. Answers using for loop are not expected.

Comment: Are these actually nested hashes/arrays, or rather ActiveRecord objects with assocations? If the former, your case has nothing to do with Rails. However, for the latter, you'd want to use the database to compute that.

Comment: @D-side these are nested hashes I am collecting this information for reporting purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it this way:

```
# convert to list of categories hashes
list = array.map {|h| h['categories'] }.flatten

sum_hash = list.inject({}) do |carry, h|
  name = h['category_name']
  # initiate new Category or get if it's already existed
  carry[name] ||= {'category_name' => name, 'weight' => 0}
  # increase weight
  carry[name]['weight'] += h['weight']
  carry
end
```

Your output:

```
{
  "Presentation"  => {"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>36},
  "Speaking"      => {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>25},
  "Communication" => {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>25}
}
```

Now just convert received hash to array:

```
{ 'categories' => sum_hash.map { |_, v| v } }
```

Comment: Thanks @vladra. Your answer is satisfactory and well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
r = a.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, e|
  e['categories'].each do |c|
    hash[c['category_name']] += c['weight']
  end
  hash
end

{'categories' => r.map { |k, v| {'category_name' => k, 'weight' => v} }}
```

And result:

```
{"categories"=>[
  {"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>36},
  {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>25},
  {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>25}
]}
```

Comment: you have also done it right. Your answer is also accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Here find my Answer**

```
sum_array = []
teachers_array = [{"teacher_name"=>"Imran Ahmad", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>24}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>20}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>20}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"t@kpi.com", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>12}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>5}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>5}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"t2@kpi.com", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"tt@kpi.com", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"asd@kpi.con", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]},
 {"teacher_name"=>"Tofiq Ahmad", "categories"=>[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>0}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>0}]}]

teachers_array.each do |teacher|

  teacher['categories'].each do |category|
    found = sum_array.select{|value| value['category_name'] == category['category_name']}[0]
    if found.present? then
      sum_array.collect! {|value|
        if value['category_name'] == category['category_name'] then
          value['weight'] += category['weight']
        end
        value
      }
    else
      sum_array << {'category_name' => category['category_name'], 'weight' => category['weight']}
    end
  end

end
```

**output**

```
[{"category_name"=>"Presentation", "weight"=>36}, {"category_name"=>"Speaking", "weight"=>25}, {"category_name"=>"Communication", "weight"=>25}]
```